# Flux action not updating state, am I doing this wrong?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I have a Flux problem that's been killing me.  I'm calling an action on page load, but for some reason it doesn't update the state in the component. In this example, I have `this.props.count` set to 5 (the default in TestStore).  I then call an action to increase it in `componentDidmount` to 6, but it doesn't update the component's state.  It stays at 5.  Then if I click the link to manually update it, it goes from 5 to 7.

I think it has something to do with the Flux changeListener being added to the top-level component after the action is dispatched?

If I put the changeListener in `componentWillMount` instead of  `componentDidMount` in the top-level component, then everything works.  But that doesn't seem like the proper way?  I feel like I'm missing something.

Here's a console.log and the components...

[image: console.log]

**< Tester />**

```
import React from 'react';
import TestActions from '../actions/TestActions';

export default class Tester extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // this.props.count defaults to 5
    // This brings it to 6
    TestActions.increaseCount();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // Count should display 6, but shows 5
        Count: {this.props.count} 
        <br />
        <a href="#" onClick={this._handleClick}>Increase</a>
      </div>
    );
  } 

  _handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    TestActions.increaseCount();
  }

}
```

**< Application />**

```
import React from 'react';
import {RouteHandler} from 'react-router';
import TestStore from '../stores/TestStore';

export default class Application extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
    this.state = this.getStateFromStores();
  }

  getStateFromStores() {
    return {
      count: TestStore.getCount()
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    TestStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  }

  _onChange() {
    this.setState(this.getStateFromStores());
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    TestStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <RouteHandler {...this.state} {...this.props}/>
    );
  }

}
```

**TestStore**

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatchers/AppDispatcher');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var TestConstants = require('../constants/TestConstants');
var assign = require('object-assign');

var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

var _count = 5;

function increaseCount() {
  _count = _count + 1;
}

var TestStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

  getCount: function() {
    return _count;
  },

  emitChange: function() {
    console.log('TestStore.emitChange');
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },

  addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    console.log('TestStore.addChangeListener');
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },

  removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }
});

AppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
  var text;

  switch(action.actionType) {
    case TestConstants.INCREASE_COUNT:
      increaseCount();
      TestStore.emitChange();
      break;

    default:
      // no op
  }
});

module.exports = TestStore;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the issue is in `<Application />`: You start listening to the store in `componentDidMount`, whereas you should do that in `componentWillMount`, otherwise you start listening to changes after all the components are mounted, therefore you lose the initial increment.

```
componentWillMount() {
    TestStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  }
```

Anyway, I would suggest to perform the action in the top component:

In `<Application />`

```
componentDidMount() {
    TestActions.increaseCount();
}, 

_handleClick() {
    TestActions.increaseCount();
},

render() {
   return <Tester callback={this._handleClick} count={this.state.count} />
}
```

In `<Tester/>`

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.props.callback}>Increase</a>
```

Comment: I see.  I saw that that fixed the problem it when I changed it to `componentWillMount`.  But I didn't know if that was the solution or not.  Just because every tutorial I've read has had changeListeners in `componentDidMount` ... I didn't know if there was a reason for that or not :)  I was thinking maybe there was a way to fire the action after all parent components have mounted.

Comment: Well it may be more proper to use componentDidMount. In your case I would refactor the architecture, having the top component performing the actions, and the child component using callbacks to the father.

Comment: We usually add the listeners in componentDidMount. Adding them in componentWillMount will create a memory leak when running the code server-side, because mount/unmount never gets called there.

Comment: Do you need to fire the action from `<Tester />`?  Ideally, you would do all bootstrapping of the data before the initial rendering, outside of React itself.  Basically, right before you call `React.render(<Application />, myRootDiv)`, you can fire off an INITIAL_DATA_LOADED action and do all the initialization in the stores.

Comment: @fisherwebdev Yep, after thinking about it some more, I realized I didn't need to fire the action from `<Tester />`.  I put it outside of React, like you said, and everything is smooth sailing now :)  Thanks!